# Реализация чата на Андроид

Tags: android, php, java, mysql

Всем доброе утро!
Пришел к вам со следующим вопросом:
Есть желание реализовать приложение-чат по типу переписки в социальных сетях(ВКОНТАКТЕ, Facebook), поэтому интересуют следующие вопросы:

1. Что должна представлять из себя серверная часть, и на чем ее лучше реализовать?
2. Необходимо ли использовать WebSocket на серевере и на устройствах, или можно обойтись без него? Если да, то какие преимущества он дает?
3. Понимаю что нужно использовать json, вопрос - как его правильно формировать, чтобы сообщение уходило конкретному пользователю?
4. Материалы, примеры, литература, много литературы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) то, на чем можете писать. Как по мне, то для начала хорошо использовать node.js или готовый jabber клиент.

2) можно и их. Плюс только один - будет работать на windows phone (там вроде чистые сокеты не совсем работают). Но если это не Ваша целевая аудитория, то используйте обычные сокеты или http-rest.

3) как не формируй, а для того, чтобы сообщение ушло нужному пользователю, нужно просто оправить его нужному пользователю (то есть в нужный сокет, который связанный с пользователем). А вот что там будет внутри json - это дело клиента, а серверной части это все равно.

4) если честно, то я рекомендую взять любой доступный jabber сервер ( классические варианты - [ejabber](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejabberd) или [openfire](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfire) ) и библиотеку [smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) для клиента. Эта связка решит много вопросов и Вам нужно будет поработать над интерфейсом. Для большинства "выдумок" скорее всего уже будут готовые решения (расширения протокола), но никто не запрещает добавить свои.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Мое мнение по работе с сокетами, что только они без обновления(то есть без повторных запросов) будут выдавать текущую информацию. Работу с сокетами на андроид и iOS вроде уже освоил. А вот сама логика backend для меня не до конца понятна. Интересно есть каие нибудь статьи о том как реализовать собственную соц сеть, в плане базы данных, ее структуры, подхода к формированию запросов и ответов, хранения медиа файлов и другой объемной информации. Как расчитать параметры сервера на нагрузги, оценить ее пригодность для тех или иных задач.

Comment: Слишком долго будете проектировать) Начните делать, а в процессе все это ещё 100 раз изменится)

Comment: > Интересно есть каие нибудь статьи о том как реализовать собственную соц сеть, в плане базы данных, ее структуры,

я думаю, что Вы понимаете, что это тема не одной книги и многое там будет является закрытой информацией?

Но кое-что известно. Почитайте, о том, как [устроенны внутри](http://www.insight-it.ru/highload/) гиганты мира сего.

Comment: До гигантов еще далеко! Но вот не понятно одно: при выкладке видео, оно сначала заливается в исходном формате, и только потом проходит конвертацию,или конвертация происходит в процессе заливки? И какой софт на серваке использовать для этих целей? Есть ли бесплатный?

Comment: делать "налету" не всегда возможно. Может банально не хватить ресурсов. Поэтому, обычно вначале закачивают, а потом потихоньку конвертируют. Для конвертации можно использовать ffmpeg (в некоторых дистрибутивах называется avconv). И бесплатный (там есть некоторые лицензионный особенности с некоторыми кодеками, но все бесплатно и с сорцами), и выполнит практически все задачи по конвертированию и преобразованию видео и звука.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду копать в данном направлении. А как Вы считаете первоначально есть необходимость в возможности добавления видео и аудио файлов? Или лучше сначала реализовать основной функцинал соцсети, а далее переходить к подобным вопросам?

Comment: я думаю, что такие вопросы возникнут. И не только видео/аудио. Поэтому, наверно стоит при разработки делать некий универсальный объект-плейсхолдер. А потом, только нужно будет дописывать "плагины". Неизвестные типы для начала можно заменять на картинки-заглушки.

А может Вам просто взять готовый движок социальной сети, например [diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/) и посмотреть, как оно там?